# What cartoon had a white stick figure protagonist with an M-shaped girlfriend?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I used to watch this cartoon series when I was very little (I'm 19, I probably watched it in the early 2000s). I can't remember much but I'll write down whatever I can.

- I first saw the show in the early 2000s.
- The protagonist was a semi-stickfigure man, completely colored in white.
- He had a girlfriend/fiance/wife, who's name was M or Maria and had an M shaped body.
- The setting and the story was overall very dark and mature for a cartoon (at least as far as I remember) with themes such as nuclear apocalypse, loss of loved ones etc.
- The language was English.
- I am not sure of the country of origin.
- I remember a radioactive apocalypse in which the protagonist (who might be a scientist/vigilante) seeks shelter in an underground vault/lab.
- I remember the specific quote "The shelter needs to be at least a hundred **Kilometers** under the ground to withstand a nuclear attack."
- I remember giant red ants inhabited the surface after the event, the protagonist mentioned radioactive fallout to be the cause of their drastic size change.
- A supercomputer type character kidnapped/murdered(?) the protagonist's girlfriend.

I'd love to be able to watch this show again! Please respond if you got a clue!

Comment: If you found the answer, go ahead and post it as one and them mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

*The OP edited his post to add an answer; according to the OP, it was a series called "Kutlas".*

> SOLVED - A friend of mine helped me found out the title! It's Kutlas, I suggest anyone interested to watch it. Definitely worth the time.

*But it's not as easy to find even with that information, hence my answer.*

---

This seems to be one or more episodes of *[Cuttlas](https://calpurnio.wix.com/calpurnio#!cuttlas/cjg9)*, also known as *[El Bueno de Cuttlas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuttlas)*<sup>‡</sup>, drawn by [Calpurnio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calpurnio)<sup>‡</sup>. "Kutlas" seems to be a transliteration, probably in Persian (the language on the page where I found it was identified as Persian by Chrome).

It features Cuttlas, who YouTube shows to be a semi-stick figure in all white, and his girlfriend Mabel, although she does not look like a letter M.

According to WikiPedia, it had a run as an animated series in the early nineties and has been shown on Comedy Central and Cartoon Network.

<sup>‡: Source in Spanish.</sup>

Comment: While this could easily be an incorrect memory on the OP's part, it does not look like Mabel (his girlfriend) "had an M shaped body".

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I agree; the most important clue I used was the OP's own find of 'Kutlas', the transliteration of the original name. I originally wanted to make a CW answer just to have an answer here, but when I found out it wasn't as easy as that, I did the work and decided to make a regular answer out of it.

Comment: Ah! I had not looked at the question's edit history to see that. Now I can upvote this answer. Since the question was edited to remove this information, it might be appropriate to include the fact that the OP found the answer. This answer would also be improved by including more information about *Cuttlas*, especially that his girlfriend's name was Mabel and that it was drawn with stick figures on a white background. Moving an OP's answer update from the question to an answer is *the right move*.